# bodyScrollEnd event is not getting triggered in windows OS chrome browser on 125% scaling [ag-grid-vue]

Tags: windows, vue.js, vuejs2, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

**Environment to reproduce**
Windows 8,10,11
"vue": "2.5.16"
"ag-grid": "18.1.2"
"ag-grid-vue": "26.2.0"

**Browser**:
Chrome 96.0.4 +

**Providing a Reproducible Scenario**

1. Set the windows display resolution to scale to 125% or 150% Open the
2. chrome and open the app
3. https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-example-forked-gy47e?file=/src/App.vue
4. Now try to scroll to bottom of the grid `bodyScrollEnd` is not
   triggering when scroll reaches the end

[image: bodyScrollEndImg]

CodeSandBox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-vue-example-forked-gy47e?file=/src/App.vue

**Current behavior**
bodyScrollEnd event is working fine on MacOS BigSur(11.6) and Windows (on 100% scaling) on every browser

**Expected behavior**
bodyScrollEnd event should be triggered on reaching end or scroll irrespective of OS and browser

**AG Grid version**: 18.1.2

**Browser**:
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36'

**Language**: [ES6/7]

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this even in chrome with 100% resolution. Getting `ScrollEndTriggered` value as false.